# java.net.UnknownHostException : api.openweathermap.org

Tags: java, android, json, unknown-host

I'm following a course on udacity 'Developing Android Apps'. Following is the code of ForecastFragment class which is suppose to get data in json format from the url(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Delhi,in&mode=json&cnt=7&units=metric).

```
public  class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

          }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] data = {

                "Today-Sunny-34", "Tommorow-Rainy-233", "Wednesday-Cloudy-21", "Thursday-Monayblue-18", "Frida-Rainy-23", "Saturday-Rainy-22", "Sunday-Strorm-100"
        };


        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);



        return rootView;
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater){

       inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_refresh){
            FetchWeatherTask fetch = new FetchWeatherTask();
        fetch.execute();
        return true;}

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Delhi,in&mode=json&cnt=7&units=metric");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();


                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) return null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }
                if (buffer.length() == 0) return null;
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Forecast Json String" + forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("placeholder fragment", "error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm repeatedly getting this error.

```
07-20 12:49:14.063    2392-2486/com.example.android.sunshine.app        E/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Error
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.openweathermap.org
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:512)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:300)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:259)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
        at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:119)
        at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:83)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

Following are the things I've already checked:-

- mobile phone has internet access.
- AndroidManifest.xml declares the permission for internet usage.

  The url works fine in the browser,but I'm clueless as to why this error is coming up.

Also, I'm running the app on my android phone(api 10).

If anyone could please provide a solution or point me in the right direction,it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Could you also include the full stacktrace that you're getting this error from?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Yet I did not turn WiFi on on my mobile phone. Activating wifi solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your Async class as-is and ran it in a new project on a KitKat VM on my Mac machine. Here are the results:

```
07-19 14:40:32.070    1670-1683/centerorbit.com.myapplication V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast Json String{"city":{"id":1273294,"name":"Delhi","coord":{"lon":77.216667,"lat":28.666668},"country":"IN","population":0},"cod":"200","message":0.0095,"cnt":7,"list":[{"dt":1437285600,"temp":{"day":29,"min":28.21,"max":29,"night":28.21,"eve":29,"morn":29},"pressure":984.15,"humidity":88,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"speed":1.66,"deg":64,"clouds":36},{"dt":1437372000,"temp":{"day":29.15,"min":25.17,"max":31.21,"night":27.92,"eve":31.21,"morn":26.55},"pressure":986.25,"humidity":95,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":3.22,"deg":86,"clouds":88,"rain":10.65},{"dt":1437458400,"temp":{"day":30.46,"min":25.15,"max":31.57,"night":27.94,"eve":31.1,"morn":25.15},"pressure":988.81,"humidity":83,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":6.41,"deg":111,"clouds":68,"rain":0.45},{"dt":1437544800,"temp":{"day":30.63,"min":26.12,"max":32.69,"night":28.12,"eve":32.69,"morn":26.12},"pressure":991.01,"humidity":81,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"speed":3.57,"deg":118,"clouds":64},{"dt":1437631200,"temp":{"day":34.27,"min":25.81,"max":35.34,"night":27.1,"eve":33.11,"morn":25.81},"pressure":989.86,"humidity":78,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":2.06,"deg":74,"clouds":8,"rain":3.94},{"dt":1437717600,"temp":{"day":31.12,"min":25.71,"max":31.12,"night":26.68,"eve":30.83,"morn":25.71},"pressure":991.3,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":1.06,"deg":184,"clouds":13,"rain":7.82},{"dt":1437804000,"temp":{"day":31.68,"min":25.88,"max":32.17,"night":27.01,"eve":32.17,"morn":25.88},"pressure":989.57,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":1.28,"deg":226,"clouds":52,"rain":5.89}]}
```

It appears that your code is fine, and something is not right with your system/network. I would recommend restarting your phone/computer to see if that fixes the issue. If not, try using a different network (disconnect from your home WiFi and use Cell network).

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply..........As suggested, I restarted the system and also tried with mobile data instead of wifi. Both cases I got the same error. Also i've edited the question to add the full stacktrace.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the URL that you are trying to call into the browser on your phone and tell me if it loads the JSON?

Comment: opening the url(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Delhi,in&mode=json&cnt=7&units=metric) on my phone's browser, it says that the data can't be displayed and gives the option to download it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have registered permission in androidManifest to access Internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Append APIKey at the end of URL
To get APIKey you have to create acount on **openweathermap.org**
       e.g.  http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Delhi,in&mode=json&cnt=7&units=metric**&appid=yourapiid**"

Detail Process to Get APIKey is
[image]

Comment: I apply these Steps and Now URL is working in Sunshine App

Comment: Consider reading a little about [the markdown flavour formatting used on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).  By making your answers look clean, you're increasing the chances they will be useful.

Comment: Is my answer is useful or clear to you friends?   If my Formatting is not Good/Effective then please give me an (Demo formatting) of my above solution?